# Wordpress 4.9 session_start in theme function

Tags: php, wordpress, session, editor

I use session_start in the start of WordPress theme function. I set value for session values in admin ajax function. it is all working fine.

When I try to edit a certain theme file from an editor in WordPress admin it cannot save throwing an error like

> "Unable to communicate back with the site to check for fatal errors, so
>   the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file
>   change by some other means, such as by using SFTP"

If I removed session_start from the function then it works fine to edit from the admin page.

Is there any alternate way to start function

Comment: Saminathan K are you from coimbatore ?

Comment: No I am from Chennai

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try wrapping session_start()

```
if(!session_id()){
    session_start()
}
```

Just my guess, since i didn't see your code